# Shared drive not available after formatting on Windows network

Tags: windows, networking

I have two Windows machines on my LAN. One has Windows 7 Home Premium the other has Vista Home Premium. On the W7 machine I have a K: drive which is shared with full control for everyone. This drive was accessible from the Vista machine until I formatted the drive. The drive is visible on the Vista machine but when I try to access it I get "K:\ is not accessible. Access is denied".

How can I make the drive accessible?

For what it's worth, I am the only user of both machines so I don't bother with user accounts or passwords.

Edit: The W7 machine has other drives which are also shared and which are available to the Vista machine. As far as I can determine, the sharing settings for the accessible drives are the same as for K:

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I needed to re-set the drive's Security permissions. Right-click on the drive and choose Properties. Click on the Security tab. In my case the missing "user" was "Everyone". I added that and gave them full control and my drive was useable from my other machine. (Giving them full control is probably not necessary to make the share work.)